# Antd Button onClick Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am getting a typescript error when working with the button component from Ant Design library. "**Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.**" I am not sure how to fix this.

Component JSX

```
<Button onClick{() => toggleSideMenu('guidance')} icon={<CompassFilled/>} type='default' />
```

toggleSideMenu function:

```
  const toggleSideMenu = (menu: string) => {
      switch (menu) {
        case 'guidance':
          setIsGuidanceVisible(!isGuidanceVisible);
          break;
        case 'bluetext':
          setIsBlueTextVisible(!isBlueTextVisible);
          break;
        case 'tasklist':
          setIsTaskListVisible(!isTaskListVisible);
          break;
        case 'projectsnapshot':
          setIsProjectSnapshotVisible(!isProjectSnapshotVisible);
          break;
        default:
          return false;
          break;
      }
  };
```

Is there a way to rewrite this to fix this issue or something else I can do? Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove `return false;`

Comment: Still throwing same error.

Comment: could you try `onClick{() => {toggleSideMenu('guidance')}}` (curly braces around the function body)? If so, it's the issue @captain-yossarian mentioned, that a handler must return void. On the other hand, your error message would be different if that were the problem, so I'm not 100% sure if this fix will help.

Comment: Resolved. See my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was that the TypeScript plugin I was using was caching and throwing the error. As soon as I rewrote the components that had this issue, the error went away.